# Report an error (Error converting data type varchar to float) when I was doing an query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

```
select * from fb_lab_test 
where (report_item_code = 'HBcAb' and result like '%positive%') 
or (
    report_item_code = 'Anti-Hbc' and 
    case isnumeric(result) when 1 then cast(result as float) else 10000.0 end > 0.2
)
```

I have two conditions in this SQL, when I use either of them, no error, but when I add the `OR`, there is an error:

> Error converting data type varchar to float

Anyone could help? Thanks a lot.

Here is sample data

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE fb_lab_test(
    [id] [numeric](18, 0) IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Test_No] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [execute_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [PatientId] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Visit_Id] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Patient_Type] [int] NULL,
    [PatientName] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [result_date_time] [datetime] NULL,
    [report_item_name] [varchar](256) NULL,
    [report_item_code] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [result] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO fb_lab_test values('5910315197','2019-10-31 00:40:53.000','111111','1','1','Tom','2019-10-31 08:56:54.000','test1','KET','-')
```

Comment: Please show some sample data that reproduces the issue.

Comment: `isnumeric` is not a precise function and can return false positives. Hence why its important to see sample data.

Comment: Actually,there is no report_item_code  = 'Anti-Hbc'  in my 'fb_lab_test',but it's still report an error...

Comment: As I said, please show some sample data that produces a [mre].

Comment: you are right,error from the data,let me check it out

Comment: In this sample data,`isnumeric` will return false positives,but `case isnumeric(result) when 1 then cast(result as float) else 10000.0 end > 0.2` should never be evaluated, that's the source of the issue

Comment: OK,thank you very much for helping

Comment: Why have you tagged an unsupported version of SQL Server?  Please explain if you are really using SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server can get pretty funny with expressions that convert values. Even if it seems like if should be filtered out, sometimes the query processor will evaluate the values anyway. Sometimes you can get around it by changing the query a little.

Try ...

```
select * from fb_lab_test where (report_item_code = 'HBcAb' and result like '%positive%')
union 
select * from fb_lab_test where report_item_code = 'Anti-Hbc' and 
    case isnumeric(result) when 1 then cast(result as float) else 10000.0 end > 0.2
```

Comment: And the bonus prize - there is a good chance it will perform better.

Comment: I guess that is it,thanks a lot and to @DaleK too,sorry for my bad English

Comment: @EricZ no worries

Comment: You might want to consider using `union all` unless you specifically want to avoid duplicates, its just that the de-duping of `union` means its significantly slower than `union all`.

Comment: UNION ALL can result in duplication if a record matches both conditions.

Comment: ^^^ Yes :) as I said, but worth making the OP aware about the performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a supported version of SQL Server, then don't use `isnumeric()`!  And avoid `case` expressions in the `where` clause.  I think you want:

```
select *
from fb_lab_test
where (report_item_code = 'HBcAb' and result like '%positive%') or
      (report_item_code = 'Anti-Hbc' and 
       (try_cast(result as float) > 0.2 or try_cast(result as float) is null)
      );
```

Answer (score -1):

In your query, result column has been used with **Like** operator with value to compare as varchar.

```
result like '%positive%'
```

In the last condition you are casting result to float, which is giving error.

If result is 5, it will be cast.
If result is ‘xyz’, it won’t be cast.

Comment: But OP is using the `isnumeric` function to check whether the string is a number before attempting the convert - which is why they are asking.

Comment: FYI: the term is "cast" not "casted" :)

Comment: You have used OR condition in the WHERE condition, which means either first condition will set true or both will set true or one will true and another will be false. Consider the scenario when first condition sets to false, and second statement(inside) will be executed so:- report-item-code gave ‘anti-hbc’ and you are anding this with 10000.0, so in short, you can multiply two float but can’t multiply one float and one varchar.

Comment: i can delete```result like '%positive%'```, still got error,none of business of it,still thanks

Answer (score -1):

If no error when you used either of them. So you can deal it by query statement as below:

```
SELECT * FROM fb_lab_test 
WHERE 1=1 
AND report_item_code = 'HBcAb' 
AND result LIKE '%positive%'

UNION ALL

SELECT * FROM fb_lab_test 
WHERE 1=1
AND report_item_code = 'Anti-Hbc' 
AND CASE ISNUMBERIC(result) WHEN 1 THEN CAST(result AS float) ELSE 10000.0 END > 0.2
```

Comment: Appears to identical as the existing answer from Jason?

Comment: I just saw his answer after I posted my answer.

Comment: Whats with the `1=1`? That could easily confuse someone new to SQL.

Comment: Nothing for 1=1, it just my style in writing sql statement. It's useful for me to comment out some condition.